# How do "Your Speed" Signs work, and how do vehicles know when it's the sign's turn to display their speed?

Tags: civil-engineering, roadway, radar, traffic-light

I see these LED speed signs on the side of the road, which display the approaching vehicle's speed.

What I have gathered is that they measure the time between the sending and receiving of the signals and then convert it into distance. My questions are:

- How is it displayed for each vehicle on the lane which are also moving forward at the same time (like cars from left to right)?
- How effective is it if the drivers just see the number on the sign change but they are not sure of which vehicle's speed the sign is currently displaying?

I have already checked out [the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_speed_sign) on how radar speed signs work, but they don't explain the mechanism. I would love to know how they work in detail, and how the signs address the speed issue in countries with wide roads and high traffic like India.

[image: your speed sign]

[image]

Comment: It would make more sense to me if these were doppler, not time of flight like a police radar gun but cannot confirm.

Comment: theyre about as effective as they make drivers recheck their spedometers

Comment: vehicles do not know anything ... the drivers would be the ones to know

Answer (score 2):

These are almost certainly Doppler systems (addressing some comments).  The transmitted beam, be it radar or lidar, is focussed and aimed to cover the approaching lane at a decent distance.  If it's aimed too near the sign, the pointing angle will be significantly not parallel to the vehicle motion, leading to a $cos{\theta}$ error in the measurement.   If it's aimed too far, the intent of the system is lost.

There's only one receiver element (so far as I know), so  the largest amplitude received signal is the one which will be used to calculate the oncoming speed.  There isn't any azimuth/elevation rejection used, and I rather doubt there's any prioritization of multiple returns. After all, if two or more vehicles are approaching at significantly different speeds, they're going to hit each other first :-) .

Comment: the sign in my neighborhood detects multiple targets and cycles through displaying the speed of three fastest objects ... it has a range of about 250 meters

Comment: @jsotola   You clearly have a high-tech government there :-)